# How to redirect to a different page after authenticated with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have bought a template in envato which is quite complex, I know a bit of react, I am not an expert yet, however I managed to integrate Azure AD Authentication into the app.

I used this procedure:
https://github.com/salvoravida/react-adal

My app is like this:

DashApp.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store, history } from "./redux/store";
import PublicRoutes from "./router";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { LocaleProvider } from "antd";
import { IntlProvider } from "react-intl";
import themes from "./settings/themes";
import AppLocale from "./languageProvider";
import config, {
  getCurrentLanguage
} from "./containers/LanguageSwitcher/config";
import { themeConfig } from "./settings";
import DashAppHolder from "./dashAppStyle";
import Boot from "./redux/boot";

const currentAppLocale =
  AppLocale[getCurrentLanguage(config.defaultLanguage || "english").locale];


const DashApp = () => (
  <LocaleProvider locale={currentAppLocale.antd}>
    <IntlProvider
      locale={currentAppLocale.locale}
      messages={currentAppLocale.messages}
    >
      <ThemeProvider theme={themes[themeConfig.theme]}>
        <DashAppHolder>
          <Provider store={store}>
            <PublicRoutes history={history} />
          </Provider>
        </DashAppHolder>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </IntlProvider>
  </LocaleProvider>
);
Boot()
  .then(() => DashApp())
  .catch(error => console.error(error));

export default DashApp;
export { AppLocale };
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import DashApp from './dashApp';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

import { runWithAdal } from 'react-adal';
import { authContext } from './adalConfig';

const DO_NOT_LOGIN = false;

runWithAdal(authContext, () => {

  ReactDOM.render(<DashApp />, document.getElementById('root'));

  // Hot Module Replacement API
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./dashApp.js', () => {
      const NextApp = require('./dashApp').default;
      ReactDOM.render(<NextApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
    });
  }

},DO_NOT_LOGIN);


registerServiceWorker();
```

and router.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import App from './containers/App/App';
import asyncComponent from './helpers/AsyncFunc';

const RestrictedRoute = ({ component: Component, isLoggedIn, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props => isLoggedIn
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: '/signin',
            state: { from: props.location },
          }}
        />}
  />
);
const PublicRoutes = ({ history, isLoggedIn }) => {
  return (
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div>
        <Route
          exact
          path={'/'}
          component={asyncComponent(() => import('./containers/Page/signin'))}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path={'/signin'}
          component={asyncComponent(() => import('./containers/Page/signin'))}
        />
        <RestrictedRoute
          path="/dashboard"
          component={App}
          isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
        />
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  );
};

export default connect(state => ({
  isLoggedIn: state.Auth.get('idToken') !== null,
}))(PublicRoutes);
```

The authentication is working fine, but its redirected to a custom login page the template has, I want the redirect to be to /dashboard instead.

Thats the question, should be easy, but new to react routing

Comment: Take a look on this guide https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Give a try. (I'm not 100% sure - I just made a guess from the given code)

---

router.js

```
const PublicRoutes = ({ history, isLoggedIn }) => {
  return (
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <div>
        <Route
          exact
          path={'/'}
          render={() => <Redirect to="/dashboard" />}
        />
        <Route
          exact
          path={'/signin'}
          component={asyncComponent(() => import('./containers/Page/signin'))}
        />
        <RestrictedRoute
          path="/dashboard"
          component={App}
          isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
        />
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  );
};
```

Comment: thanks Ritwick, it worked, maybe you know something about this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305568/how-to-integrate-azure-ad-into-a-rect-web-app-that-consumes-a-rest-api-in-azure

Comment: I don't know much about azure ad but I'm checking if I can help :)