# How to integrate azure ad into a react web app that consumes a REST API in azure too

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I have one web app which is React, and I already configured Azure AD Authentication for the web app itself.  Its 100% Client site app, no server side components.

I used this component:
https://github.com/salvoravida/react-adal

My code is as follows:
adalconfig.js

```
import { AuthenticationContext, adalFetch, withAdalLogin } from 'react-adal';

export const adalConfig = {
  tenant: 'mytenantguid',
  clientId: 'myappguid',
  endpoints: {
    api: '14d71d65-f596-4eae-be30-27f079bf8d4b',
  },
  cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
};

export const authContext = new AuthenticationContext(adalConfig);

export const adalApiFetch = (fetch, url, options) =>
  adalFetch(authContext, adalConfig.endpoints.api, fetch, url, options);

export const withAdalLoginApi = withAdalLogin(authContext, adalConfig.endpoints.api);
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import DashApp from './dashApp';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

import { runWithAdal } from 'react-adal';
import { authContext } from './adalConfig';

const DO_NOT_LOGIN = false;

runWithAdal(authContext, () => {

  ReactDOM.render(<DashApp />, document.getElementById('root'));

  // Hot Module Replacement API
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./dashApp.js', () => {
      const NextApp = require('./dashApp').default;
      ReactDOM.render(<NextApp />, document.getElementById('root'));
    });
  }

},DO_NOT_LOGIN);


registerServiceWorker();
```

dashapp.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store, history } from "./redux/store";
import PublicRoutes from "./router";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";
import { LocaleProvider } from "antd";
import { IntlProvider } from "react-intl";
import themes from "./settings/themes";
import AppLocale from "./languageProvider";
import config, {
  getCurrentLanguage
} from "./containers/LanguageSwitcher/config";
import { themeConfig } from "./settings";
import DashAppHolder from "./dashAppStyle";
import Boot from "./redux/boot";

const currentAppLocale =
  AppLocale[getCurrentLanguage(config.defaultLanguage || "english").locale];


const DashApp = () => (
  <LocaleProvider locale={currentAppLocale.antd}>
    <IntlProvider
      locale={currentAppLocale.locale}
      messages={currentAppLocale.messages}
    >
      <ThemeProvider theme={themes[themeConfig.theme]}>
        <DashAppHolder>
          <Provider store={store}>
            <PublicRoutes history={history} />
          </Provider>
        </DashAppHolder>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </IntlProvider>
  </LocaleProvider>
);
Boot()
  .then(() => DashApp())
  .catch(error => console.error(error));

export default DashApp;
export { AppLocale };
```

Until that point everything works fine, when the user is not authenticated its redirected to login.live.com for authentication and then its redirected back.

However I also created another azure webapp for hosting a REST API, that REST API is already configured in Azure AD, so that users that try to use the rest will need to be authenticated.

Now the question is:  How do I setup my client side APP to consume REST API which is protected by Azure AD.?

I found this and looks what I am looking for, but I am not sure how to integrate this into my existing code above

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/issues/481

Update: 
For potential readers

This answer plus the instructions on this url to configure App registrations helped me to solve the problem: https://blog.ithinksharepoint.com/2016/05/16/dev-diary-s01e06-azure-mvc-web-api-angular-and-adal-js-and-401s/

Comment: check this might help you https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/videos/protecting-web-api-backend-with-azure-active-directory-and-api-management/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The key here is `adalApiFetch`, defined in `adalConfig.js`. As you can see, it's a simple wrapper around `adalFetch`. This method  (defined in [`react-adal`](https://github.com/salvoravida/react-adal/blob/master/src/react-adal.js)) receives an ADAL instance (`authContext`), a resource identifier (`resourceGuiId`), a method (`fetch`), a URL (`url`) and an object (`options`). The method does the following:

1. Use the ADAL instance (`authContext`) to obtain an access token for the resource identified by `resourceGuiId`.
2. Add this access token to the `headers` field of the `options` object (or create one if it wasn't provided).
3. Call the given "fetch" method passing in `url` and the `options` object as parameters.

The `adalApiFetch` method (which you have defined in `adalConfig.js`) simply calls `adalFetch` with the resource identified in `adalConfig.endpoints.api`.

Ok, so how do you use all of this to make a REST request, and consume the response in your React app? Let's use an example. In the following example, we will be using the Microsoft Graph API as the Azure AD-protected REST API. We will be identifying it by it's friendly identifier URI ("https://graph.microsoft.com"), but just keep in mind that that could just as well be the Guid app ID.

**adalConfig.js** defines the ADAL configuration, and exports a couple helper methods:

```
import { AuthenticationContext, adalFetch, withAdalLogin } from 'react-adal';

export const adalConfig = {
tenant: '{tenant-id-or-domain-name}',
clientId: '{app-id-of-native-client-app}',
endpoints: {
    api: 'https://graph.microsoft.com' // <-- The Azure AD-protected API
},
cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
};

export const authContext = new AuthenticationContext(adalConfig);

export const adalApiFetch = (fetch, url, options) =>
adalFetch(authContext, adalConfig.endpoints.api, fetch, url, options);

export const withAdalLoginApi = withAdalLogin(authContext, adalConfig.endpoints.api);
```

**index.js** wraps `indexApp.js` with the `runWithAdal` method from `react-adal`, which ensures the user is signed with Azure AD before loading `indexApp.js`:

```
import { runWithAdal } from 'react-adal';
import { authContext } from './adalConfig';

const DO_NOT_LOGIN = false;

runWithAdal(authContext, () => {

// eslint-disable-next-line
require('./indexApp.js');

},DO_NOT_LOGIN);
```

**indexApp.js** simply loads and renders an instance of `App`, nothing fancy here:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

**App.js** is a simple component where the magic happens:

- We define a `state` value. In this case, it's called `apiResponse` since we're just displaying the raw API response, but of course you could name this state whatever you wanted (or have multiple state values).
- During `componentDidMount` (which is run after the element is available in the DOM), we make a call to the `adalApiFetch`. We pass in `fetch` (from the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API0) as the `fetch` parameter, and the endpoint for the REST request we want to make (the `/me` endpoint in Microsoft Graph, in this case):
- In the `render` method, we simply display this state value in a `<pre>` element.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { adalApiFetch } from './adalConfig';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    apiResponse: ''
  };

  componentDidMount() {

    // We're using Fetch as the method to be called, and the /me endpoint 
    // from Microsoft Graph as the REST API request to make.
    adalApiFetch(fetch, 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', {})
      .then((response) => {

        // This is where you deal with your API response. In this case, we            
        // interpret the response as JSON, and then call `setState` with the
        // pretty-printed JSON-stringified object.
        response.json()
          .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({ apiResponse: JSON.stringify(responseJson, null, 2) })
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {

        // Don't forget to handle errors!
        console.error(error);
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>API response:</p>
        <pre>{ this.state.apiResponse }</pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I am getting this error Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
(anonymous function)
src/containers/testREST.js:28

Comment: I can't really comment on code I can't see. Can you share the code with the error?

Comment: Oh, actually, I can see just enough of the error to guess what the problem is. Is your API (`/values`) returning JSON? `response.json()` is assuming it is, and attempting to de-serialize it, but finding a `<` character. Maybe `/values` is returning HTML or XML?

Comment: yes thats my thoughts too, I just changed the formatter to json instead of xml, testing the react app

Comment: that was the problem, thanks a lot, finally its working after 1 week struggling with this.

Comment: also this post helped me with the configuration part. https://blog.ithinksharepoint.com/2016/05/16/dev-diary-s01e06-azure-mvc-web-api-angular-and-adal-js-and-401s/

Answer (score 0):

I still had the issue with the config given above. I added on more config to the above and it worked. Hope it helps.

```
import { AuthenticationContext, adalFetch, withAdalLogin } from 'react-adal';

export const adalConfig = {
tenant: '{tenant-id-or-domain-name}',
clientId: '{app-id-of-native-client-app}',
endpoints: {
    api: 'https://graph.microsoft.com'
},
cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
extraQueryParameter: 'prompt=admin_consent'
};

export const authContext = new AuthenticationContext(adalConfig);
```

Answer (score 0):

Phillipe's response put me down the right path, but I was still running into an issue with my token not being accepted.

aadsTS700051: response_type 'token' is not enabled for the application.

To resolve I needed to go into my app's registration > manifest & set oauth2AllowImplicitFlow to true:

```
    "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": true,
```

Log out of your Azure account, sign back in & you should receive your user's details.