# Implement Azure AD with React web application

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory

Are there any examples on how to implement Azure AD with React web application the example I see include .net core examples only. Mine is pure React web application. Any suggestions?

it is ok to bundle the tenantid and clientid/application inside the react web application? would that have any security implications

Comment: Does it help  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305568/how-to-integrate-azure-ad-into-a-react-web-app-that-consumes-a-rest-api-in-azure?

Comment: I would try this. https://ahsanshares.wordpress.com/2019/10/19/react-app-consuming-microsoft-graph/

Answer (score 0):

We implemented similar structure as follows:
There is a webappservice, which is created from standart web application template. It handles all the authentication parts. Once user is authenticated, the web application service, serves react files with proper parameters (e.g. logged in, user token etc)

Comment: Could you please provide some example web app service. Is this written in react?